# Using Ploty's Splom iris code but no data showing up on my plots in rstudio

Tags: r, plotly, no-data

I am using plotly's code for their splom chart. The code is working, but the data points arent being plotted on the plots that are being created.

Here is my code

```
    pl_colorscale=list(c(0.0, '#19d3f3'),
                       c(0.333, '#19d3f3'),
                       c(0.333, '#e763fa'),
                       c(0.666, '#e763fa'),
                       c(0.666, '#636efa'),
                       c(1, '#636efa'))
   
    axis = list(showline=FALSE,
                zeroline=FALSE,
                gridcolor='#ffff',
                ticklen=4)
    
    fig <- df %>%
      plot_ly() 
    fig <- fig %>%
      add_trace(
        type = 'splom',
        dimensions = list(
          list(label='Household Income', values=~insurance$income),
          list(label='Coverage', values=~insurance$coverage),
          list(label='Claim Amount', values=~insurance$claim_amount),
          list(label='Retired Status', values=~insurance$retire)
        ),
        text=~class,
        marker = list(
          color = as.integer(df$class),
          colorscale = pl_colorscale,
          size = 7,
          line = list(
            width = 1,
            color = 'rgb(230,230,230)'
          )
        )
      ) 
    fig <- fig %>%
      layout(
        title= 'Insurance Data',
        hovermode='closest',
        dragmode= 'select',
        plot_bgcolor='rgba(240,240,240, 0.95)',
        xaxis=list(domain=NULL, showline=F, zeroline=F, gridcolor='#ffff', ticklen=4),
        yaxis=list(domain=NULL, showline=F, zeroline=F, gridcolor='#ffff', ticklen=4),
        xaxis2=axis,
        xaxis3=axis,
        xaxis4=axis,
        yaxis2=axis,
        yaxis3=axis,
        yaxis4=axis
      )
    
    fig
```

This outputs the 4x4 plots with each of the variables on the x and y axis but no data points. i am also recieving the warning about  NAs introduced by coercion for household income which i think is the same for all of the variables

Comment: Facing the same issue.